# SMO: Script partitioned tables as non-partitioned

Tags: sql-server, smo

I need to generate scripts for certain tables that are partitioned but I don't want the partitions to be scripted. For such a task, I am instantiating a scripter object and setting `Options.NoTablePartitioningSchemes = true;`

```
smoScripter.Options.AppendToFile = false;
smoScripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = false;
smoScripter.Options.NoTablePartitioningSchemes = true;
```

The generated script still places the table in a partitions:

`WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [SomeTablePartition]([SomeField])`

Is there a way to force Smo scripter to generate table scripts to place tables on primary filegroup, or at least on default?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `NoFileGroup` option. This will avoid including the `ON` clause for file groups and partition schemes. Without the `ON` clause, tables/indexes will be created on the default filegroup.

```
smoScripter.Options.NoFileGroup = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an explicit filegroup and unset the partition scheme. I did it in powershell, but it should work for any SMO implementation. On the assumption that `$t` holds a table object:

```
$t.FileGroup = 'bar';
$t.PartitionScheme = $null;
$t.Script();
```

Note - it might feel weird to change the properties on the object. Rest assured that those changes aren't made in the live database unless you call `.Alter()` on the table object.